# Apex test class without data

Tags: apex

I have a simple Apex class that needs an Apex test to promote to production (via Change Set).  All it does it deletes all the entries of an object.  All the examples of Apex Tests talk about creating test data.  But my code doesn't require data. How can the test be coded? Please advise.

```
public class InvoiceAccountPurge {
  public static void purgeInvoiceAccounts() {
    List<InvoiceAccount__c> InvAcct = [SELECT Id FROM InvoiceAccount__c];

    DELETE InvAcct;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your test does require data. A unit test for this class would need to validate that it does what you say it does:

> All it does it deletes all the entries of an object

So your unit test would create some `InvoiceAccount__c` records, then invoke `purgeInvoiceAccounts()`, and finally make an assertion that all of the records have been deleted.

If you are attempting to perform a one-off data purge, this is something you could execute via a data loader pass, requiring no Apex at all. Note that your Apex class will be subject to governor limitations, including specifically the 50,000 row SOQL limit and 10,000 row DML limit.

Comment: We want to build purge into a process.  I don't think Data Loader will be convenient for this.

Comment: Then you may need a batch class, depending on your data volume. And you certainly need a unit test.

Comment: You cannot delete that which does not exist *(spooky theremin sounds)*. To test your code that deletes something, you first need to create some data.

Comment: I would be inclined to do that sort of thing from an Apex Anonymous window.... but of course as @DavidReed indicated, if there's a lot of records, you will need a batch.